# Trying to run an automatic script to remotely transfer a file to a Raspberry Pi then reboot it

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, scripting, raspberry-pi

Bit of background, my employer has a TV screen in the entrance lobby, which is powered by a computer that shows a rolling Powerpoint slideshow. I've been asked to come up with something more efficient, and have managed to do so with a build for Raspberry Pi. The way it works is on boot it automatically loads a slideshow in a particular location, then just rolls that until powered off.

To change the content, you need to:

- Remotely transfer a new presentation with the same filename and overwrite the existing one (I tend to use WinSCP for this but FTP is also an option)
- Send the reboot command to the Pi so that it picks up the new presentation.

My problem is the person in charge of keeping the presentations up to date isn't particularly computer literate and struggles with this process.

I've found solutions where people are able to write a script either via VBS or a .bat file that opens an SSH session or similar and execute commands. Is it possible to create a script that can automatically open a remote session, take a .odp file from a given location, rename it to the necessary filename, transfer it to the right location on the Pi and send a reboot command? If so, what do you suggest would be the right way to go about doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) on the windows machine, use PSCP to transfer files, and Plink for executing commands/scripts on the Raspberry.

From the docs:

> PSCP, the PuTTY Secure Copy client, is a tool for transferring files
>   securely between computers using an SSH connection.
>
> Plink (PuTTY Link) is a command-line connection tool similar to UNIX
>   ssh. It is mostly used for automated operations, such as making CVS
>   access a repository on a remote server.

Comment: Nice! For anyone else here with the same problem, I stuck the two commands in a .bat file and made sure PSCP and Plink were in the same directory.